# C# и вложенный List

Tags: c#, list

есть 2-а List'a

```
List<int> start = new List<int>(); // список цифровой последовательности
List<List<int>> massive = new List<List<int>>(); // вложенный список
```

Во вложенный я добавляю список start (много раз, путем перезаписывания)
Задача такая, что после всех манипуляций, мне нужно вытащить список цифр которые были в start.

```
for (int i = 0; i < massive.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < massive[i][??????]; j++)
            {
                str += massive[i][j];
            }
            listBox1.Items.Add(str);
            str = "";
        }
```

Вопрос: как узнать размер вложенных когда-то списков start?

Comment: rasmisha прав, спасибо тебе.
p.s. Вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
massive.ForEach(list => listBox1.Items.Add(list.Aggregate(string.Empty, (acc, el) => acc + el)));
```

Comment: Изящный способ, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

massive[i].Count ?

Comment: только massive[i].Count-1 :)

Comment: ну это индекс последнего элемента :)

Comment: хотя проверил, и если я правильно понял, то такой вариант не катит   for (int j = 0; j < massive[i][massive[i].Count]; j++)

Comment: тов. @rasmisha имел ввиду `for (int j = 0; j < massive[i].Count]; j++)`

Comment: -_-....мда, чет я намудрил.... пойду хоккей смотреть :)